# What data to keep in React state

Tags: reactjs, react-component, react-state

In React **state** we use it for storing data like API response and managing flags, etc.

can we use the **state** for storing data that changes after some events or user action but does not shows in UI or does not need to render, but It will be sent to in API response after button click.

What exact data need to keep in the state? can someone please explain...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: if you want to preserve the value which changes often , but shouldn't trigger a re-render then you should use `ref` instead of state . because changing the state will trigger re-render .

Comment: How about storing in a variable like this.someVariable = [1,2,3]; If anything to update I will change this variable this.someVariable.push(2345). @Shyam

Answer (score 0):

I'd be cool to see what kind of data we are talking about here. Some code examples would be helpful.

Anyways, if this data is changing over time or some other components depend on this data or different components perform some operations based on that data than I think that the state is a good place for it.